# What is this style of illustration called? (see images)

Tags: illustration, style-identification

[image]

[image]

Is there is an actual name for this? I just know that people do this kind of design but I didn't know if it had a name.

Comment: Can't say much for the first image, but the faux halftone effect in the second one certainly reminds me of Pop Art. That sort of what you're after?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I have been trying to look up what the style was...the closest thing I found was pop art. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not meet our [style-identification guidelines](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2929/23061)

Answer (score -2):

Pop Art, with some cartoony approach perhaps. I am not really sure.